# Update parent component from child component

Tags: blazor, blazor-webassembly

I have a parent page with 2 child components. Child1 component should have two buttons that when you click one, the other one is disabled, and each button should add a string to a list on a model `caseDetails.Log`. That list is then displayed in Child2 component.

At first my problem was that the parent page didn't display the new lines added to the list. I got it to work with my `ClaimCase()` function from Child1 component, by creating an event callback function and calling it from `ClaimCase()` with `await UpdatePage.InvokeAsync();`

Then both buttons were working, but the list was only updated when `ClaimCase()` was called.

I then added `await UpdatePage.InvokeAsync();` to `UnclaimCase()`, but then the `disabled`-attribute on the buttons stoped updating so Claim-button doesn't get enabled when I click the Unclaim-button.

Why did this happen when I called the event callback from `UnclaimCase()` but not from `ClaimCase()`?

Parent:

```
<Child1 CaseClaimed="true" UpdatePage="UpdatePage"/>
<Child2 LogList="@caseDetails.Log"/>
    
@code {
private void UpdatePage(){}
}
```

Child1:

```
<button disabled=@CaseClaimed @onclick="ClaimCase">Claim</button>
<button disabled=@(!CaseClaimed) @onclick="UnclaimCase">Unclaim</button>

@code {
[Parameter]
public bool CaseClaimed { get; set; }

[Parameter]
public EventCallback UpdatePage { get; set; }

private async Task ClaimCase()
{
    CaseClaimed = true;

    caseDetails.Log.Insert(0, $"User claimed case");

    await UpdatePage.InvokeAsync();

}

private async Task UnclaimCase()
{
    CaseClaimed = false;

    caseDetails.Log.Insert(0, $"User unclaimed case");

    await UpdatePage.InvokeAsync();

}
```

Child2:

```
@if (LogList != null)
{
    foreach (var log in LogList)
    {
        <p>@log</p>
    }
}

@code {
    [Parameter]
    public List<string> LogList { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Please, reproduce it in [blazor repl](https://www.telerik.com/blazor-ui/repl). I bet the problem is in a detail that you have omited here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whilst you have solved your immediate problem, wiring up multiple components with event callbacks is not a sustainable solution in a complex multi-component page.

Here's a design based on the limited information in your question that demonstrates the Notification pattern for inter-component communications.

It uses a presentation layer service to hold and manage the data required by the components, with an event that is raised when the Log changes.  The top level form cascades the presenter instance and the components on the page interact with the cascaded presenter.

First the presentation layer service to hold and manage the data:

```cs
public class CasePresenter
{
    public List<string> Log { get; private set; } = new List<string>();
    public event EventHandler<EventArgs>? LogChanged;
    public bool CaseClaimed { get; private set; }

    public CasePresenter() 
    { 
        // inject any services
    }

    public async Task LoadAsync()
    {
        // Load your data from the data pipeline
        await Task.Delay(100);
        this.Log= new List<string>();
    }

    public void ClaimCase()
    {
        CaseClaimed= true;
        this.Log.Add($"User claimed case at {DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString()}");
        this.LogChanged?.Invoke( this, EventArgs.Empty );
    }
    public void UnClaimCase()
    {
        CaseClaimed = false;
        this.Log.Add($"User unclaimed case at {DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString()}");
        this.LogChanged?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);
    }
}
```

Registered in `Program`

```cs
builder.Services.AddTransient<CasePresenter>();
```

Your button component:

```cs
<div>
    <button class="btn btn-success" disabled="@this.Presenter.CaseClaimed" @onclick="() => this.Presenter.ClaimCase()">Claim</button>
    <button class="btn btn-danger" disabled="@(!this.Presenter.CaseClaimed)" @onclick="() => this.Presenter.UnClaimCase()">Unclaim</button>
</div>

@code {
    [CascadingParameter] private CasePresenter Presenter { get; set; } = default!;

    protected override void OnInitialized()
        => ArgumentNullException.ThrowIfNull(this.Presenter);
}
```

Your notes list component:

```cs
@implements IDisposable
<h3>Case Notes</h3>
@foreach (var note in this.Presenter.Log)
{
    <div class="alert alert-info">@note</div>
}

@code {
    [CascadingParameter] private CasePresenter Presenter { get; set; } = default!;

    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        ArgumentNullException.ThrowIfNull(this.Presenter);
        // wire up event handler to Render the component when the log changes
        this.Presenter.LogChanged += this.OnLogChanged;
    }

    private void OnLogChanged(object? sender, EventArgs e)
        => this.InvokeAsync(StateHasChanged);

    // Dispose the event handler
    // Note component @implements IDisposable
    public void Dispose()
        => this.Presenter.LogChanged -= this.OnLogChanged;
}
```

And your form/page:

```cs
@page "/"
@inject CasePresenter Presenter

<PageTitle>Index</PageTitle>

<h1>Hello, world!</h1>

<CascadingValue Value=Presenter IsFixed>
    <CaseClaimer />
    <CaseNotes />
</CascadingValue>

@code {
    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        await Presenter.LoadAsync();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem was solved when I set the value of `CaseClaimed` after the eventcallback in ClaimCase and UnclaimCase functions.

Like this:

```
caseDetails.Log.Insert(0, $"User claimed case");

await UpdatePage.InvokeAsync();

CaseClaimed = true;
```